# Connecting to a host address with Android

Tags: android, sockets, http

I have a server address that I want to connect my app to.

```
This is his address: "http://54.148.194.246:8080/".
```

I try to connect to it by this code:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("http://54.148.194.246/", 8080);
```

But my app gives me this error :

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "http://54.148.194.246/": No address associated with hostname.
```

I added Internet permission and my wireless is on (those were the answers that I saw for this problem).

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try connecting with some other device and it worked? maybe you have some server issues?

Comment: Also try connecting to that address from that same device using a browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove `http://`from the IP/hostname when passing it to the `Socket` constructor:

```
clientSocket = new Socket("54.148.194.246", 8080);
```

Alternatively, use the [`URL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) class for sending HTTP requests specifically:

```
URL url = new URL("http://54.148.194.246:8080/");
InputStream strm = (InputStream) url.getContent();
// use strm as needed...
```

Or:

```
URL url = new URL("http://54.148.194.246:8080/");
URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
// use conn as needed...
```